# Python: Upload files via requests too fast?

Tags: python, file, upload

I noticed that script that i written "uploads" files very very fast... I have 500kbs upload speed, so upload 1GB file in under 2 minutes is absolutely not possible.

Upload code:

```
with open(local_path, 'rb') as f:
    files = MultipartEncoder({'files[]': (filename, f, 'application/octet-stream')})
    UploadFile = requests.post(self.UploadURL, data=files, allow_redirects=False, headers={'Content-Type': files.content_type})
```

I used software called "Fiddler4" to check how much data is being sended, additionally this upload code works fine with 1-100MB files but 1GB files causes that Server is closing connection so i getting `[Errno 32] Broken Pipe` error

Comment: I'm just thinking out loud here- is adding a delay a bad idea?

Comment: I'm thinking about chunks usage... But dunno how to implement it